# Traverse a Decision Tree based on User Input

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

I'm currently studying decision trees, and have implemented my own. The dataset I used is of phone apps. It has the following feature names:

App Name, Category, Ratings, Reviews, Size, Installs, Type, Price, Content Rating, Genres, Success

"Success" is based off of Ratings

My X has: Category, Reviews, Size, Installs, Type, Price, Content Rating, Genres

My Y is: Success

The goal is to build the decision tree, and make a short program that reads each node, then asks the user information based on that node. For example the first node is Reviews, so the program will prompt the user to input the number of Reviews. It then reads the second node which is, say Type, then it will prompt the user to input the Type of the app, etc.

My code is very long, so for the sake of the example, I will use the code here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/tree/plot_unveil_tree_structure.html

My question is: Given the decision tree, how do I traverse the tree based on user input?

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier

iris = load_iris()
X = iris.data
y = iris.target
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, random_state=0)

estimator = DecisionTreeClassifier(max_leaf_nodes=3, random_state=0)
estimator.fit(X_train, y_train)

# The decision estimator has an attribute called tree_  which stores the entire
# tree structure and allows access to low level attributes. The binary tree
# tree_ is represented as a number of parallel arrays. The i-th element of each
# array holds information about the node `i`. Node 0 is the tree's root. NOTE:
# Some of the arrays only apply to either leaves or split nodes, resp. In this
# case the values of nodes of the other type are arbitrary!
#
# Among those arrays, we have:
#   - left_child, id of the left child of the node
#   - right_child, id of the right child of the node
#   - feature, feature used for splitting the node
#   - threshold, threshold value at the node
#

# Using those arrays, we can parse the tree structure:

n_nodes = estimator.tree_.node_count
children_left = estimator.tree_.children_left
children_right = estimator.tree_.children_right
feature = estimator.tree_.feature
threshold = estimator.tree_.threshold


# The tree structure can be traversed to compute various properties such
# as the depth of each node and whether or not it is a leaf.
node_depth = np.zeros(shape=n_nodes, dtype=np.int64)
is_leaves = np.zeros(shape=n_nodes, dtype=bool)
stack = [(0, -1)]  # seed is the root node id and its parent depth
while len(stack) > 0:
    node_id, parent_depth = stack.pop()
    node_depth[node_id] = parent_depth + 1

    # If we have a test node
    if (children_left[node_id] != children_right[node_id]):
        stack.append((children_left[node_id], parent_depth + 1))
        stack.append((children_right[node_id], parent_depth + 1))
    else:
        is_leaves[node_id] = True

print("The binary tree structure has %s nodes and has "
      "the following tree structure:"
      % n_nodes)
for i in range(n_nodes):
    if is_leaves[i]:
        print("%snode=%s leaf node." % (node_depth[i] * "\t", i))
    else:
        print("%snode=%s test node: go to node %s if X[:, %s] <= %s else to "
              "node %s."
              % (node_depth[i] * "\t",
                 i,
                 children_left[i],
                 feature[i],
                 threshold[i],
                 children_right[i],
                 ))
print()

# First let's retrieve the decision path of each sample. The decision_path
# method allows to retrieve the node indicator functions. A non zero element of
# indicator matrix at the position (i, j) indicates that the sample i goes
# through the node j.

node_indicator = estimator.decision_path(X_test)

# Similarly, we can also have the leaves ids reached by each sample.

leave_id = estimator.apply(X_test)

# Now, it's possible to get the tests that were used to predict a sample or
# a group of samples. First, let's make it for the sample.

sample_id = 0
node_index = node_indicator.indices[node_indicator.indptr[sample_id]:
                                    node_indicator.indptr[sample_id + 1]]

print('Rules used to predict sample %s: ' % sample_id)
for node_id in node_index:
    if leave_id[sample_id] == node_id:
        continue

    if (X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]] <= threshold[node_id]):
        threshold_sign = "<="
    else:
        threshold_sign = ">"

    print("decision id node %s : (X_test[%s, %s] (= %s) %s %s)"
          % (node_id,
             sample_id,
             feature[node_id],
             X_test[sample_id, feature[node_id]],
             threshold_sign,
             threshold[node_id]))

# For a group of samples, we have the following common node.
sample_ids = [0, 1]
common_nodes = (node_indicator.toarray()[sample_ids].sum(axis=0) ==
                len(sample_ids))

common_node_id = np.arange(n_nodes)[common_nodes]

print("\nThe following samples %s share the node %s in the tree"
      % (sample_ids, common_node_id))
print("It is %s %% of all nodes." % (100 * len(common_node_id) / n_nodes,))
```

I'm thinking of using the for loop to iterate through the nodes, but I'm not sure where to start.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm interested in something like this as well.